# What is the value of voltage controlled switch to demodulate the PAM circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, ltspice, pulse, demodulation

[image]
What is the possible value of V3 (voltage controlled switch) and the command to demodulate PAM signal?

Comment: I get the feeling you simply copied that schematic from somewhere and didn't pay attention enough. Do look again, particularly around the area you're pointing at. Also, are you sure that schematic does what you think it does?

Comment: That appears to function as a voltage controlled open/closed switch. At very low speeds a relay would do the job. At higher speeds a transmission gate or a MOSFET (or two series opposed) would word. Look at ye olde CD4016 transmission gate for a starting idea.

Comment: https://components101.com/ics/cd4016-quad-bilateral-switches-multiplexer

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4016b.pdf?ts=1624186637732&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4016B